# Xamarin Forms (Sqlite error)

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, xamarin

I keep getting these errors what does it mean?

Failed to load assembly from stream

Please see my logs below :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Failed to load assembly from stream: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/External/.nuget/packages/sqlitepclraw.provider.e_sqlite3.android/1.1.5/lib/MonoAndroid/SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0017d] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00012] in <5a7d391011b47c3aa745038310397d5a>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/External/.nuget/packages/sqlitepclraw.provider.e_sqlite3.android/1.1.5/lib/MonoAndroid/SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0017d] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00012] in <5a7d391011b47c3aa745038310397d5a>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/External/.nuget/packages/sqlitepclraw.provider.e_sqlite3.android/1.1.5/lib/MonoAndroid/SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0017d] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00012] in <5a7d391011b47c3aa745038310397d5a>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 <---
<---            1
```

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI0J8.png)

Comment: Please share your code. Reading this can help you improve your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of SQLite PCL Raw you are using should have some problems...
Check this thread: [e_sqlite3.dll doesn't get loaded](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/issues/181)

Try to get the latest version from Nuget (v.1.1.10) or try a newer version in the PRE release Nuget channel.

Tell me if it's ok...

Comment: i see the problem when i run my application to xamarin live player the error occur , but when i archive/export my app to apk it works just fine. so is there any chance to run it to xamarin live player

Comment: i'm using the latest sqlite version from nuget